# Making conclusions in a z test for a proportion

Tags: statistics, p-value

A poll from a previous year showed that $10\%$ of smartphone owners relied on their data plan as their primary form of internet access. Researchers were curious if that had changed, so they tested $H_0: p=10\%$ versus $H_a:p\neq10\%$
where $p$ is the proportion of smartphone owners who rely on their data plan as their primary form of internet access. They surveyed a random sample of $500$ smartphone owners and found that $13\%$ of them relied on their data plan.

The test statistic for these results was $z\approx 2.236$, and the corresponding P-value was approximately $0.025$.

Assuming the conditions for inference were met, which of these is an appropriate conclusion?

$a)$ At the $\alpha=0.01$ significance level, they should conclude that the proportion has changed from $10\%$.

$b)$ At the $\alpha=0.01$ significance level, they should conclude that the proportion is still $10\%$.

$c)$ At the $\alpha=0.05$ significance level, they should conclude that the proportion has changed from $10\%$.

$d)$ At the $\alpha=0.05$ significance level, they should conclude that the proportion is still $10\%$.

The correct answer is $c$ but why could it not have been $b$? Why is it $c$?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- (c) has $0.05$ while (b) has $0.01$
- Your choices are conventionally *"reject the null hypothesis"* or *"do not reject the null hypothesis"*, but not *"accept the null hypothesis"* which is close to the wording of (b) and (d)

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by your first point. Also I don't see the words in point two in any of the choices.

Comment: You found $p=0.025$.  That would have been significant with $\alpha=0.05$ as in (c) and (d) but not with $\alpha=0.01$ as in (a) and (b).  So that leaves (b) and (c) as possible conclusions.  (c) has *"conclude that the proportion has changed"* which is essentially *"reject the null hypothesis that the proportion has not changed"* so looks reasonable, while (b) has *"the proportion is still $10\%$"* which is essentially *"accept the null hypothesis of no change"* so not reasonable in conventional hypothesis testing

Comment: Is this because $.05$ is the standard for this type of testing? Because isn't it if the p value is higher than the significance level you accept the null hypothesis?